# Using Trello to 'iterate' / give feedback on tasks that are marked as staged or done

Tags: kanban, team

We are using Trello for project management of a dev project. Here is how we are working currently:

Developer takes a card assigned to them from the Todo pile and moves it to Doing then the
 Developer works on card and moves it to Done.

Then the task / module / card has to be tested for functionality / bugs etc so what often happens is that the cards get moved back to Doing as more info is added into the comments section of the card about something not working / looking right.

Is this the best way to iterate / give feedback on cards? Or is there a better / more accepted or standardized workflow? Would you have a staged or for testing column in between Doing and Done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### I recommend the Agile/Scrum approach

You can slice this many different ways but I recommend the Agile/Scrum approach:

1. Don't have any sub-teams within the dev team. Team members may have deep expertise in one of the areas (Design, Dev, QA). However, let them make a team commitment to completing the work and operate as a cross-functional team. This means testing will happen in parallel with development. So, you won't need a separate 'Testing' column.
2. A business person - Product Owner or Product Manager - will accept a story as done either based on a demo or by testing it as a user. So, you need a 'In Review' column.

So, have a 'To Do', 'In Progress', 'In Review' and 'Done' columns.

Whenever anyone doing a test finds an issue, they show it to the team members writing code and it gets fixed and verified within the dev team. I have bug tickets created in the backlog only if a bug cannot be resolved on the same day or, at most, the next day. This allows the story to be accepted and let the bug be prioritized by the Product Owner. For example, if a feature is working on the newer browsers but not on IE7, you may not want to hold up the feature. The Product Owner may lower prioritize it based on usage.